# Angular HttpParams vs string URL

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http

I would like to understand more about HttpParams. I have a simple Data Service in my Angular app with 2 functions - **getWithHttpParams, getWithURLParams.**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService2 {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWithHttpParams(apiUrl:string, ID: string) {
    const reqParams = new HttpParams().set('ID', ID);
    return this.http.get(Configuration.apiPath + apiUrl, {params: reqParams}).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }

  getWithURLParams(apiUrl:string, ID: string) {
    return this.http.get(Configuration.apiPath + apiUrl + "?ID=" + ID).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test to test this service.

```
it('should make a GET request with HttpParams', () => {

    service.getWithHttpParams('test', '123').subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual('test data');
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(Configuration.apiPath + 'test?ID=123')
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    expect(req.request.params.get('ID')).toEqual('123');

    req.flush('test data');
});

it('should make a GET request with URL Params', () => {

    service.getWithURLParams('test', '123').subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual('test data');
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(Configuration.apiPath + 'test?ID=123')
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    expect(req.request.params.get('ID')).toEqual('123');

    req.flush('test data');
});
```

So the 1st test which uses getWithHttpParams passes but the 2nd test which uses getWithURLParams fails. What's the reason for this?

Comment: You just passed params in URL manually, you didn't create an HttpParams, that's why `req.request.params` is empty. Why would you manually pass in URL? You can achieve the same result with HttpParams which is more readable.

Comment: So, if the original request did not create the params with utils like HttpParams, will the tests not know about params, even though the URL has params? More importantly, from a test engineer's perspective, how will you test it?

Comment: You can check the source code https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71309d223d26dfe5b0681a13725a872c8ba58fae/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L210 , it looks like I thought, angular doesn't parse your url to create an HttpParams object. If you didn't pass `options.params` then it just creates new instance of HttpParams.